# TableAdapter not updating identity

Tags: c#, sql-server, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

I use a TableAdapter to update the database like this:

```
var changes = anpDatabase.AnpCollection.GetChanges();
anpCollectionTableAdapter.Update((AnpDatabase.AnpCollectionDataTable)changes);
anpDatabase.AnpCollection.Merge(changes);
anpDatabase.AnpCollection.AcceptChanges();
```

However this isn't enough to update the identity primary column... I tried putting changing the Insert Command of the adapter to the following:

```
INSERT INTO AnpCollection
                  (ParentCollectionId, StartDate, EndDate, Completed, IsPartial, Partitioned, IsAutomaticallyGenerated)
VALUES     (@ParentCollectionId,@StartDate,@EndDate,@Completed,@IsPartial,@Partitioned,@IsAutomaticallyGenerated);
SELECT CollectionId, ParentCollectionId, StartDate, EndDate, Completed, IsPartial, Partitioned, IsAutomaticallyGenerated FROM AnpCollection WHERE (CollectionId = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

However, If I do this, instead of the column being updated, a new row appears with the correct identity value... That's not what I want... Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving the `INSERT` statement with the `SELECT` at the end, it seems like the right code here is:

```
anpCollectionTableAdapter.Update(anpDatabase.AnpCollection);
```

instead of:

```
var changes = anpDatabase.AnpCollection.GetChanges();
anpCollectionTableAdapter.Update((AnpDatabase.AnpCollectionDataTable)changes);
anpDatabase.AnpCollection.Merge(changes);
anpDatabase.AnpCollection.AcceptChanges();
```